# Alpha Vantage API Key returns invalid error in Python, and what is Response[200]?

Tags: python, python-requests, alpha-vantage

Using the following code, I am not getting any data from [alphavantage](https://www.alphavantage.co/), I get the following API error:

> ```
> "Error Message": "Invalid API call. Please retry or visit the documentation (https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/) for TIME_SERIES_DAILY." }
> ```

```
import requests
import alpha_vantage

API_URL = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query"

data = {
    "function": "TIME_SERIES_DAILY",
    "symbol": "NIFTY",
    "outputsize": "compact",
    "datatype": "csv",
    "apikey": "xxx",
    }
response = requests.get(API_URL, params=data)
print(response.json())
```

I edited the code to try something else, but I still got something strange, this time it was:

`Response [200]`

Here is the code for that:

```py
import requests
import alpha_vantage

API_URL = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query"

data = {
    "function": "TIME_SERIES_DAILY",
    "symbol": "US",
    "outputsize": "compact",
    "datatype": "csv",
    "apikey": "xxx"
    }
response = requests.get(API_URL, params=data)
print(response)
```

What going on here?
(Key obfuscated below to `xxx`)

Comment: Please edit your question to give what the error you're getting is. Also, Alpha Vantage only provides US ETFs, and doesn't have NIFTY index data. Also, you need a comma after "csv".

Comment: the error is simple : the API key is not valid. it seems that Python library, does not accept free registration API keys, maybe only the paid ones. and thank you for the notes

Comment: You need to add the exact error to your question. Please edit your question. There is no way that's what the error you're getting from the above code. The above code doesn't compile. 

Please copy and paste the exact error message, and the exact code you ran to get that error message, and put it into your original question.

Comment: What do you mean by extracting error ? what is the command for that  ? or I simply copy the error message? btw this last line has invalid syntax : print(response.json())[/code]

Comment: ok I replaced NIFTY with US , and print(response) , I got : <Response [200]> . Don't even know what it is

Comment: That's better, let me edit your question for clarity and I'll respond below. Please don't add API keys to example text (apologies, I did say for you to put your exact code). EDIT: The suggested edit queue is full

Comment: try:
print(response.text)
You'll get an error with that. Please put the error into your question. (US isn't a valid ticker)

Comment: I did it. so it seems that this code does not give me much information. I am still at the very starting point, and I see this website should be premium to give me some information.

Comment: Great, hopefully my edits to your question are approved. See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three issues going on with your attempts to call this API.

1. In your first attempt, you correctly call the API but use an invalid ticker. `NIFTY` along with other global indexes are not supported by the [Alpha Vantage API](https://www.alphavantage.co/).
2. On your second attempt, you print out a response object, which when converted to string looks just like the output you received, `Response[200]` meaning a successful API call was made. To get the data from it, you have to print `response.text` or `response.json()`
3. The third issue is more subtle, and depends on what you are trying to return. If you want to return a csv file using the `datatype: "csv"`, you cannot use `response.json()` since the format isn't for json. You can instead use the default `datatype: "json"`, by leaving that field blank.

If you want to get a csv file, you can use `print(response.text)`

JSON example

```py
import requests
import alpha_vantage

API_URL = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query"

data = {
    "function": "TIME_SERIES_DAILY",
    "symbol": "M&M.NSE",
    "outputsize": "compact",
    "apikey": "xxx"
    }
response = requests.get(API_URL, params=data)
print(response.json())
```

CSV example

```py
import requests
import alpha_vantage

API_URL = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query"

data = {
    "function": "TIME_SERIES_DAILY",
    "symbol": "M&M.NSE",
    "outputsize": "compact",
    "datatype": "csv",
    "apikey": "xxx"
    }
response = requests.get(API_URL, params=data)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: I just tried the JSON example, but all I got was `{}` (using the same symbol, and my working key).

Comment: Try a different symbol? Data availability has changed over the years

Comment: I figured it out. I only can use symbols composed of letters only. If they contains a dot (`.`) it does not work, or any other symbol..

Comment: If you do https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=DIGITAL_CURRENCY_DAILY&symbol=BTC&market=USD&apikey=demo on the docs it also says invalid